# The use of a hyphen (»-«) in the formation of compound adjectives

Tags: adjective, hyphen

The below paragraph appears in the article from *Der Spiegel* called "[Hollande redet sich um Kopf und Kragen](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/fran-ois-hollande-buch-bringt-franzoesischen-praesidenten-in-not-a-1116767.html)". The article talks about the French President François Hollande and a recently published book documenting his hard-hitting comments about various people of influence in France.

> Warum macht er das [that is, why Hollande makes all these nasty comments], rätselt die Nation über die geballte Ladung von menschenverachtender Bosheit. Ausgerechnet der Mann, der sich im Wahlkampf vom Bling-Bling-Stil Sarkozys absetzen wollte und versprach, einen normalen Präsidenten zu geben, erscheint in Wahrheit als **giftig-galliger** Miesepeter. Und wo ist der Charmeur, der umgängliche Strippenzieher, der geschickte "Mann der Synthese"? Angesichts seiner haarsträubenden Bekenntnisse schrumpft er zum verbitterten, isolierten Rumpelstilzchen des Élysée.

As far as I know, it's not a common practice in German to form compound adjectives by connecting their component parts by a hyphen. In this case, however, it seems clear that hyphen is used for clarity purposes, since *giftig(-)gallig* is a brand new word (no matches for *giftiggallig* in Google search).

My question is: If I want to form a compound German adjective for which no dictionary entry currently exists (for instance, *politisch(-)erfahren* = *politically experienced*), should I use a hyphen to separate the component parts of such an adjective?

Comment: politically experienced -> **politikerfahren**

Comment: Or *politisch erfahren*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [official spelling rules](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) (in German) as published by the [*Rechtschreibrat*](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de) have an entire section (section C) devoted to the use of hyphens.

In the prefacing remarks, they note that there are three groups that are covered by the ruleset:

> - Zusammensetzungen und Ableitungen, die keine Eigennamen als
>     Bestandteile enthalten (§ 40 bis § 45)
> - Zusammensetzungen und Ableitungen, die Eigennamen als Bestandteile enthalten (§ 46 bis § 52)
> - Gruppen, in denen man den Bindestrich setzen muss (§ 40 bis § 44;
>     § 46 und § 48 bis § 50), und solche, in denen der Gebrauch des
>     Bindestrichs dem Schreibenden freigestellt ist (§ 45, § 51 bis § 52).

Translated:

> - Compound words and derived words that do not contain proper nouns as their constituents (§ 40 to §45)
> - Compound words and derived words that do contain proper nouns as their constituents (§ 46 to § 52)
> - Groups, in which a hyphen has to be typeset (§ 40 to § 44; § 46 and § 48 to § 50) and those in which the use of a hyphen is at the discretion of the writer (§ 45, § 51 to § 52).

§ 40 concerns single letters, abbreviations and digits *(A-Dur,* etc.), § 41 concerns suffixes with the aforementioned, *(x-te)*, § 42 concerns digits with a suffix as part of a compound and § 43 concerns  a certain set of compound nouns *(Auf-die-lange-Bank-schieben)*. The paragraphs relevant for your question are § 44 and § 45:

> § 44 Man setzt einen Bindestrich zwischen allen Bestandteilen mehrteiliger Zusammensetzungen, in denen eine Wortgruppe oder eine Zusammensetzung mit Bindestrich auftritt, **sowie in unübersichtlichen
>   Zusammensetzungen aus gleichrangigen, nebengeordneten Adjektiven.**
>
> § 45 Man kann einen Bindestrich setzen zur Hervorhebung einzelner Bestandteile, zur Gliederung unübersichtlicher Zusammensetzungen,
>   zur Vermeidung von Missverständnissen oder beim Zusammentreffen von drei gleichen Buchstaben.

Translation:

> § 44 A hyphen is typeset in between all constituents of multi-part compounds wherein a word group or compound with a hyphen occurs, **as well as in unclear compounds made up of coordinate adjectives.** (Ephasis mine in both languages.)
>
> § 45 It is permitted to typeset a hyphen to emphasise single constituents, to structure unclear compounds, to avoid misunderstandings or when three identical letters would otherwise meet up.

The question is whether a word such as *giftig-gallig* is to be considered unclear enough for § 44 to kick in or whether it is covered by § 45. So let’s take a look at the official examples presented after § 44:

> *der wissenschaftlich-technische Fortschritt, ein lateinisch-deutsches Wörterbuch, deutsch-österreichische Angelegenheiten; manisch-depressives Verhalten; physikalisch-chemisch-biologische Prozesse*

The examples listed with § 45 do not contain any adjectives and non of the following exceptions make any not to adjectives. However, I can think of compounds such as *giftiggrün* where I would not want to separate the two constituents with a hyphen because … I can’t really argue properly, but I definitely wouldn’t call it unclear.

To sum it up: § 45 *allows* hyphen for structuring unclear compounds and § 44 *requires* it for coordinate adjectives.

---

Your example is not covered by these rules. *Politisch erfahren* must be spelt as two words because they are two words. If they were two adjectives, they would not be coordinate (note the lack of a comma); but they aren’t even two adjectives. As you can see from your translation *(politically),* you are dealing with the combination of adverb and adjective. These are (almost? I feel the need to add a back door here before a counter-example is presented in the comments) never compounds and thus always separated.

Comment: I actually would consider *giftiggallig* to look considerable unclear. IMHO, the hyphen is very well covered by §44. I do see, however, another reason for the hyphen not explicitly mentioned in the rules: A non-hyphen compound to me somehow implies the first adjective *modifies or details* the second - like in *giftgrün* or *messerscharf*, which is probably not intended here - Here, I see the intention to be more like "giftig **und** gallig"

Comment: My personal advice is this: If you write an application for employment as a teacher for German language: Check your text against all official rules that you know, and make it as correct as possible. If you still re in doubt, then reword your text; use other construction patterns. But if you write anything else: Make yourself understandable. The purpose of any language is to transport messages. It's purpose is not to meet rules. If you write a perfectly correct text that nobody will understand, then you did it wrong. If you can increase understandability only by breaking rules: Do it!